# Z transform expansion with power series

Tags: power-series, z-transform

I am working on this problem and struggling to apply the power series.

[image]

**EDIT**: splitting $(z+1)/(z-1)$ into $z/(z-1) + 1/(z-1)$ and then using a table of $z$ transform might work?

**EDIT**:This is my current solution/attempt
\begin{aligned}
X(z) &= \frac{z+1}{z-1}\\
     &= 1 + \frac {1}{z} * \frac{1}{1+1/z}
\end{aligned}
Then using the power series for the 2nd part of the eqn:
$$
= 1 + 1/z\left(\frac {1}{1-z^{-1}}\right)
$$

$n0$: $1$

$n1$: $1$

$n2$: $2$

$n3$: $1.5$

$n4$: $1.3$

This is just my current attempt, I apologise if i have used mathjax incorrectly, its my first attempt!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting images.

Comment: Hi, thanks for letting me know about MathJax! I didn't realise this was used to type questions, sorry about that and thanks :)

Comment: Mathematicians who want to answer this may have to look up "z-transform", since they call it "Laurent series" instead.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{z+1}{z-1}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{z} }{1-\frac{1}{z}}=\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z^n} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z^n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}$$
$$\frac{z+1}{z-1}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{z^{n}}$$
$$\mathcal{Z}^{-1}\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)_{(n)}=\begin{cases}1 \qquad \text{if}\quad n=0 \\2 \qquad\text{if}\quad n \geq 1 \end{cases}
$$
$\mathcal{Z}^{-1}$ denotes the inverse Z-transform.